# Cannot find element inside div with xpath or css selector

Tags: python, css, selenium, xpath, element

I am trying to get "January 27" as output with this code:

```
task_offer_deadline = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="table"]/div[2]/div/a/div[1]/span[2]/div/em').text
```

the xpath provided by Google Chrome Console. This was the html source:

```html
<div class="content table-contents">
    <a class="one is-incomplete" href="/authors/tasks/5e2ad33c2b3dc80013d3dba6">
        <div class="left part">
            <span class="ref">
                <em>C33-8823</em>
                <strong class="date"></strong>
            </span>
            <span class="deadline-or-countdown">
                <div class="deadline-at">
                    <em class="green">January 27</em>
                </div>
            </span>
```

but it cannot be found. I even tried with other types of search, id, class name, all to no avail.
Any clues why? thanks a lot!

Comment: did any of the answers solve your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this xpath:

```
xpath = //span[@class='deadline-or-countdown']/div[@class='deadline-at']/em
```

If this also doesn’t help, then make sure your element is not inside the `<iframe>`.

If the element is in the iframe, then you need to switch to it before looking for the element:

```
iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@name='Dialogue Window']")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```

Comment: found the issue: the url to be searched was not complete without the filtering parameters

Answer (score 2):

Try with below `css` using `webdriver` wait with `visibility` of element

```
xpath = "//em[.= 'C33-8823']/../..//em[2]"
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
    .until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
element.text
```

you need below import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: I got this issue:`File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: `

Comment: @MartR  Please try now. I have updated the solution.

Comment: same error... `File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: `

Comment: @MartR: I formatted the HTML code in your question and found an issue with the xpath in this answer. I edited this answer to fix the issue.

Comment: @GregBurghardt i hv missed one div parent. Thank you

Comment: @MartR Please try again. Else I will see something else.

Answer (score 1):

It happened the page had some display filters that change the url and I was searching on the wrong url.

adding the filter parameters to the address `?statuses%5Bin_progress%5D=1.` made it work. Thanks for having a look everyone!